# Missing an assembly reference when using Mono.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite, mono

I'm trying to use SQLite in unity for scoring purposes by following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SHz8mm-4Pw.
I'm using UNITY 5.3.5, Visual Studio 2015 and .Net framework: 4.6.

This error appeared when I add:`using Mono.Data.Sqlite;`

> Assets/Scripts/DataBaseManager.cs(4,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name Data' does not exist in the namespace Mono'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

The Mono.Data.Sqlite DLL file had been put into the Assets>Plugins folder and Assets folder but the error is still the same.

*This dll can work previously, until I installed modules: Web Player, Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Unity, Windows Build Support using Download Assistant to solve other issues.

Hope to hear any of your advise on how to solve this issue. Thank you very much!

[Screenshoot of Visual Studio and Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2j8V.png)

Answer (score 2):

I already solved the problem. Previously I'm using 32bit Unity. The version is change to 64bit when i use the download assistant. Therefore, I reinstall using 32bit and follow this instruction to install other modules without affecting the 32bit version: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1110749/how-to-get-the-pc-standalone-module-loaded-into-th.html. It works well again! Thank you.